# Excel Chart Straight Lines with 90 degree angles

Tags: excel, charts

As you can see with the chart, each line is connected with direct lines that go from one data point to the next. I would like them to look like a stair step, all 90 degree angles. I hope I am being clear here. Attached the incorrect looking chart below.

[Chart with curved lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy5YG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your data points as date-value? So:

- 01-01-2019  4.0
- 01-04-2019  3.5
- 01-05-2019  3.0

If so, the easiest thing to do is to add the last date before the new value, like so:

- 01-01-2019   4.0
- 31-03-2019   4.0
- 01-04-2019   3.5
- 30-04-2019   3.5
- 01-05-2019   3.0

That gives you a more step-like chart, see e.g. this tutorial: https://excelchamps.com/blog/step-chart-excel/